# java.time.DateTimeFormatter : Need ISO_INSTANT that always renders milliseconds

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format

I'm trying to cleanup a mix of various code around datetime management to only Java 8 [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) namespace. Right now I have a small issue with the default [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). The [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) formatter only shows milliseconds when they are not equal to zero.

The epoch is rendered as `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` instead of `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

I made a unit test to explain the problem and how we need to final dates to be compared one to each other.

```
@Test
public void java8Date() {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
    String epoch, almostEpoch, afterEpoch;

    { // before epoch
        java.time.Instant instant = java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(-1);
        almostEpoch = formatter.format(instant);
        assertEquals("1969-12-31T23:59:59.999Z", almostEpoch );
    }

    { // epoch
        java.time.Instant instant = java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);
        epoch = formatter.format(instant);
        // This fails, I get 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z instead
        assertEquals("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", epoch );
    }

    { // after epoch
        java.time.Instant instant = java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(1);
        afterEpoch = formatter.format(instant);
        assertEquals("1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z", afterEpoch );
    }

    // The end game is to make sure this rule is respected (this is how we order things in dynamo):
    assertTrue(epoch.compareTo(almostEpoch) > 0);
    assertTrue(afterEpoch.compareTo(epoch) > 0); // <-- This assert would also fail if the second assert fails

    { // to confirm we're not showing nanos
        assertEquals("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", formatter.format(Instant.EPOCH.plusNanos(1)));
        assertEquals("1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z", formatter.format(Instant.EPOCH.plusNanos(1000000)));
    }
}
```

Comment: The default format will also only render nanoseconds if they are different from zero. If you always want milliseconds (and never nanoseconds), why not simply use a custom formatter, like `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));`?

Comment: I wanted to stay as close as possible to the formatter used for `Instant::toString()`. Maybe I should have just used a string pattern indeed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OK, I looked at the the source code and it's pretty straightforward:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendInstant(3).toFormatter();
```

I hope it works for all scenarios, and it can help someone else. Don't hesitate to add a better/cleaner answer.

Just to explain where it comes from, [in the JDK's code](https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/342a565a2da8abd69c4ab85e285bb5f03b48b2c9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java#L1164),

`ISO_INSTANT` is defined like this:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_INSTANT;
static {
    ISO_INSTANT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendInstant()
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, null);
}
```

And `DateTimeFormatterBuilder::appendInstant` is declared as:

```
public DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendInstant() {
    appendInternal(new InstantPrinterParser(-2));
    return this;
}
```

And the constructor `InstantPrinterParser` signature is:

```
InstantPrinterParser(int fractionalDigits)
```

Comment: Would be nice if you linked to the examined source code.

Comment: So how do we change this to only include ms and not nano

Comment: @user1172490 I added some code in the sample code to confirm this formatter is not rendering nanos

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted Answer by Florent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042457/642706) is correct and good.

I just want to add some clarification.

The mentioned formatter, [DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT), is default only for the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. Other classes such as `OffsetDateTime` and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) may use other formatters by default.

The java.time classes offer a resolution up to [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), much finer granularity than [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). That means up to 9 digits in the decimal fraction rather than merely 3 digits.

The behavior of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` varies by the number of digits in the decimal fraction. As the doc says (emphasis mine):

> When formatting, the second-of-minute is always output. The nano-of-second *outputs zero, three, six or nine digits* as necessary.

So depending on the data value contained within the `Instant` object, you may see any of these outputs:

> 2011-12-03T10:15:30Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.100Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.120Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.123Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.123400Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.123456Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.123456780Z
>
> 2011-12-03T10:15:30.123456789Z

The `Instant` class is meant to be the basic building block of java.time. Use it frequently for data passing, data storage, and data exchange. When generating String representations of the data for presentation to users, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).