# LocalDateTime formatter that always returns at least milliseconds

Tags: java, java-time

I need to construct a formatter, that for each `LocalDateTime` object will print at least up to milliseconds precision, or more if available (in ISO format).

For example I expect the following

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00").format(...) // 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000
LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00.123456").format(...) // 2018-01-01T00:00:00.123456
```

Answer on [java.time.DateTimeFormatter : Need ISO_INSTANT that always renders milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042134/java-time-datetimeformatter-need-iso-instant-that-always-renders-milliseconds) is not helpful, as it is for `ZonedDateTime`. Also pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` does not work for me, as it is trimming micros and nanos.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a `DateTimeFormatter` in this way to achieve the effect of printing at least milliseconds:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").appendFraction(
        ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND,
        3,
        9,
        true
    ).toFormatter();

String s1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00").format(dtf);
String s2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00.123456").format(dtf);  

System.out.println(s1); // 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000
System.out.println(s2); // 2018-01-01T00:00:00.123456
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is letter 'n' placed 1 to 9 times, which gives nano-of-second. If specified less then 9 times the nanoseconds value will be truncated to the length of number of 'n's. 'SSS' should be working as well. The format is not dependant t which class you are using it, so `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` should work the same except the fields specific to some class, like in this case time zone only present in `ZonedDateTime` and not in the `LocalDateTime`. In any case you can read about it here: [Class DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Just to add to the issue, I once was asked to write a Date parser for a String without knowing format in advance, I.e. I needed to check if the String represents a Date in any known format and parse it. I managed to write such a feature and wrote an article that explains the principle of my design. Here is the link to the article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/