# Clojure java-time: getting instant with millis

Tags: clojure, java-time

I'm trying to convert a local-date into an instant with millis using java-time, but instant returns a timestamp without millis.

```
(def UTC (java-time/zone-id "UTC")

(defn local-date-to-instant [local-date] 
  (-> local-date
      (.atStartOfDay UTC)
      java-time/instant))

(local-date-to-instant (java-time/local-date))
=> #object[java.time.Instant 0xdb3a8c7 "2021-05-13T00:00:00Z"]
```

but

```
(java-time/instant)
=> #object[java.time.Instant 0x1d1c27c8 "2021-05-13T13:12:31.782Z"]
```

The service downstream expects a string in this format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Comment: Do you need the fraction always to be there for a later `.toString()`? Because the default printer/toString will not output if zero (see https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/86bd44fe80c6222f81662b2167c402571ed68f43/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L3505)

Comment: That's right, the service downstream expects a string in this format: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Comment: Then you will have to use your own formatter.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042134/java-time-datetimeformatter-need-iso-instant-that-always-renders-milliseconds (either the accepted answer or the first comment of the question for just a formatter string - whatever is easier with java-time)

Comment: @Neikon Are you sure that that’s a requirement? The format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and according to that standard the fraction of second is optional when it is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `DateTimeFormatter` that prints an ISO instant with milliseconds (3 fractional digits) even if they are zeroes:

```clj
(ns steffan.overflow
  (:require [java-time :as jt])
  (:import (java.time.format DateTimeFormatterBuilder)))

(def iso-instant-ms-formatter
  (-> (DateTimeFormatterBuilder.) (.appendInstant 3) .toFormatter))
```

Example of use:

```clj
(def today-inst (jt/truncate-to (jt/instant) :days))

(str today-inst)                                ; => "2021-05-13T00:00:00Z"
(jt/format iso-instant-ms-formatter today-inst) ; => "2021-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).  Then you can write code like:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
String text = date.format(formatter);
```

In particular, look at these format pattern codes:

```
S   fraction-of-second  fraction    978
A   milli-of-day        number      1234
n   nano-of-second      number      987654321
```

I think the `S` code is the best one for your purposes.  You'll have to experiment a bit as the docs don't have all the details.

Here is one example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.java-time :as tjt]
  )
  (:import
    [java.time Instant LocalDate LocalDateTime ZonedDateTime]
    [java.time.format DateTimeFormatter]
  ))

(dotest
  (let [top-of-hour (tjt/trunc-to-hour (ZonedDateTime/now))
        fmt         (DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
       ]
    (spyx top-of-hour)
    (spyx (.format top-of-hour fmt))
  ))
```

with result

```
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
top-of-hour => #object[java.time.ZonedDateTime 0x9b64076 "2021-05-13T07:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]"]
(.format top-of-hour fmt) => "2021-05-13 07:00:00.000"
```

The above is based from [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) and the library [tupelo.java-time](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.04.13/api/tupelo.java-time).

Comment: Uppercase `S` is indeed the correct pattern letter to use here. The docs may be terse and assuming something, but I believe they have all the details when you read them right. Which part were you missing?

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDate` doesn't have a time component. `.atStartOfDay` puts zeroes in all time fields. A `LocalDateTime` can be converted to an `Instant` through `.toInstant`.